# Uploading apt packages to Nexus in specific folders within a repo?

Tags: debian, nexus, apt

I have a locat Nexus repo manager that I use for testing. I have added an apt repo, and within this repo I have pushed couple of packages. I am annoyed by the organization of folders though. It adds unnecessary folders under which the package is uploaded. The image below shows that.
Now, I want to customize those folders naming, how can I do that?
[image]

Comment: Is this for proxy or hosted?

Comment: @joedragons Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design see [GitHub source](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/35ed4a33eedf4f2c9196a9df283fae1580175a6d/plugins/nexus-repository-apt/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/apt/internal/AptBrowseNodeGenerator.java#L64). And there are no possibilities to customize this path. 
But you can contribute and raise a ticket, and describe things you see how to improve. 
[sonatype nexus issues](https://issues.sonatype.org/projects/NEXUS)

Answer (score 0):

As this problem persists on version 3.42.0, I raised an issue for this, https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-35767
A better answer might be available then.